# How process a Recurly subscription and transaction at the same time

Tags: recurly

When setting up a new subscription, I have the need to offer optional one-time line items, which I can process as transactions.

Right now I am developing in PHP using these two calls:
https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-transaction
https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-subscription

Each API is well documented.

What I'm wondering if there is a way to batch these events instead of calling them individually.

My use case is that the subscription is a large monthly fee:
    $subscription->create();

At this point, the CC has been charged. But now I need to start charging for the add-on one time transactions.
    $transaction_one->create();
    $transaction_two->create();

Since I'll be processing an array of charges, It gets very difficult to manage the possible CC failures in the steps here. Hence, I'm looking or a way batch the process.

Answer (score 2):

Post the adjustment first (the one-time add-on). Then, when you add the subscription to the account, and un-invoiced adjustments will be rolled up into that invoice.

The customer will get one credit card charge, and their invoice will break out each item into its own line items.

Comment: Rachel, How does authorization work then for single items? 

Basically, in my case I have a subscription and then a few items that the user might buy once at the start.

Say, for instance, this was a gym membership and you want to buy some workout clothing. 

When I call create and it is successful, will I feel that all payments will be authorized? If a transaction works but the subscription fails, do I then need to reverse the transaction?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Brian - the authorization only takes place when the subscription is added to the account without an immediate charge, or anytime billing information is updated on an account.

In the scenario above, I'll assume you're passing through billing information with the subscription create call, in which case there will be no auth, just a purchase attempt. If the transaction fails, there's no reversal needed.